What to make of 内因性 in this sentence?
「自分はいつ死んでもいいと思って生きています」
刺されて殺されても、誰かに迷惑がかからなければそれでいいと思っている。
内因性に問題を向けられ詮索される自殺ではなく、他殺もしくは不慮の事故でありたいと願っている。
The character is explaining his mind set. As far I can tell, he explains he seems death not by suicide, but in an accident so not trouble anyone.
What to make of 内因性に問題を向けられ here? I can't quite figure the nuance.


内因性 is normally used as a no-adjective meaning "endogenous/intrinsic", and it is rarely used as a standalone noun like this. In this context, it seems to refer to psychological factors that lead to suicide. Technically, the term 内因性 in a healthcare-related context does not refer to psychological factors, but let's consider the author's intent here. 内面 is the normal term to refer to someone's mind or psychological aspects in a context like this.
Xに問題を向ける is also not a common expression, but I think it means something like "to highlight X as the focus of the problem".


内因性に問題を向けられ詮索される自殺ではなく、他殺もしくは不慮の事故でありたいと願っている。
Rather than suicide, where internal causes will be focused on and scrutinized, I wish for it to be a homicide or an unforeseen accident.

While the meaning is understandable with the aid of the context, this phrasing is uncommon, so please avoid memorizing it as natural Japanese.

I guess. I was wondering if the passive meant the 内因性に was the cause but it seems I was wrong but instead it's the final direction?
問題を向けられ I take it's the usual passive "question being pointed"

Yes, that に is a direction marker (=toward) that marks the target of 向ける.
